# How can I make the arp cache refresh for a specific MAC address?

Tags: mac-address, arp

I am trying to create a VB .Net program that determines if a device is on my wireless LAN (with DHCP enabled) so I can take specific actions depending on the device there or not.

Often when I query the arp cache (using a reverse lookup routine I wrote) to determine if the device's MAC address is present, I fail to find it because the device cache timeout has expired and the device has been removed from arp.

Because the device uses DHCP to get it's IP address, I cannot query the arp cache with a "known" IP address but must use the MAC address to identify the device.

Since I am trying to quickly discover if the device is turned on or off, I want to establish whether my MAC search failure was a result of an expired cache entry or the device really being turned off.

Is there any way, knowing only the device MAC address, to force it to be be known again to arp so I can try searching the arp cache again in 30 seconds to see if an entry appeared?

Comment: Is this device something you can program? If so you can configure it to respond to a broadcast message to identify itself.

Comment: Do you *seriously* believe that anyone asking an on-topic question here **doesn't** need an answer as soon as possible? What makes you so special? I've removed the "entitled" parts at the end of your question

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the same subnet as the device, and the device will respond to broadcast ICMP pings, you can send a broadcast ping.

In my example, my machine is 129.21.49.41 on the subnet 129.21.49.0/24 (49.0 through 49.255).

- The network address for such a network is 129.21.49.0 (first address)
- The first assignable address is 129.21.49.1
- The last assignable address is 129.21.49.254
- The broadcast address is 129.21.49.255.

Here's an example:

```
angst(~) > ping 129.21.49.255
PING 129.21.49.255 (129.21.49.255): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 129.21.49.254: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0.316 ms
64 bytes from 129.21.49.205: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.422 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 129.21.49.148: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.703 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 129.21.49.31: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.766 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 129.21.49.23: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.822 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 129.21.49.246: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=13.538 ms (DUP!)
^C
```

Those are all of the machines on my subnetwork that are online that are configured to respond to broadcast pings.

Comment: Additionally, you can try using `arping`, but I've always had a lot of trouble trying to get it to work; it seems like it never actually generates inverse ARP queries.